# <a> Should only be underlined when hovering, however when I already clicked the link once (:visited) it stays underlined

Tags: html, css

I want the links to be underlined only when I hover my mouse over them. That works perfectly fine when I test in incognito mode, but when I test the link in normal mode it is already underlined when I once clicked the link/visited the page. How can I fix it and make the link only appear underlined when I hover over it?

My CSS file:

```css
a.hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.hover:link, a.hover:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.hover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And my HTML file:

```html
<p align="center">
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Paul"
     class="hover" target="_blank"><i>Ron Paul</i></a>
</p>
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen with the code you have presented.

Comment: That is what I thought but I can't find a solution. It just underlines it without hovering when I already visted the page

Comment: yup this should work, you might have some CSS overwriting these rules . @BoltClock in my  (deleted) answer the class `.hover` confused  me, and it might be the issue being overriden with some `!important` rule

Comment: Are there any style rules declared for `a:visited i`? If your rule is being over-qualified by another rule you should be able to see it in your browser IDE/ dev tool.

Comment: Okay so I tried something and figured out that every link in the normal browser (I use Chrome) is already underlined no matter if I clicked it or not. But when I go to my page in the icognito mode it is perfectly working and only underlines when I hover. Why can something work in incognito mode but not in the normal mode?

Comment: @Exred do you have any extensions? It works on my side as it should when using normal mode.

Comment: I tried in Microsoft Edge and it works. My Chrome extensions are: Adblock Plus, Floating YouTube, Valve-Devs inGame, BetterTTV, Ban Checker for Steam, Social Blade and Reddit Enhancement Suite. I don't think that any of these changes the decoration of a link. If there would be an overwriting issue it shouldn't work in incognito mode or edge?

Comment: Inspect that element, you should see where those styles are originating from in the "Styles" tab.

Comment: Thank you guys so far it shows the same in icognito and the normal mode if I inspect: 
I inspected the element and I think there might be the issue. I still don't understand why it is working in icognito/edge.
user agent stylesheet

a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: auto;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-style: initial;
    text-decoration-color: initial;
}
What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: If those styles are coming from a 3rd party browser extension the only way you may be able to overwrite it is with more specific selectors, inline-styles, or with an `!important` declaration - maybe declared as a global rule to reset vendor and 3rd-party styles such as those, e.g: `* a:visited {text-decoration: none !important}` (that will effect *every* `a` element that has been `:visited`)

Comment: The !Important solution works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`a.hover:link, a.hover:visited, a.hover:focus, a.hover:active{
    text-decoration:none;
}`

If this doesn't work for some reason, add additional selectors to increase the specificity.

example:

`body a.hover:link, body a.hover:visited, body a.hover:focus, body a.hover:active{
    text-decoration:none;
}`

If still didn't work, add !important

`text-decoration:none!important;`

Comment: Only setting none to important made it that it never underlined. So i just declared the underline important aswell and it worked! Thank you, now it works in icognito and normal mode.